# Why does 'montage' seem to take up all my disk space when I try to montage thousands of images?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-montage

I tried to 'montage' 15000 small PNG images (about 10kb each) in order to make them all into one big image, but midway through the process I get a warning that I have no disk space left. I have 30gb left in my SSD.

The command I'm running:

```
montage -mode concatenate -background none -tile "101x" "${X}_*.png" out.png
```

Why does this happen and how much disk space would I need for such a task?

Comment: What is your ImageMagick version and platform? What was your exact command line? You may be running out of memory (RAM) not disk space. Check your resource limits in ImageMagick and adjust them appropriately. `convert -list resource` and `convert -list policy`. Adjust the policy.xml file for more memory, if it is limited. You could be creating an image that is too wide, also. You may be running out of space in the your /tmp directory. See https://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php.

Comment: ImageMagick needs to read all the images into memory and then have ram for the output as well. So you are likely running out of ram.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of running out of disk space with 3 x 9GB temp files produced during the process. I had 100 1800px x 1800px PNG files to tile.

That happened without defining the width of the array. Fixing the width to 10x solved the problem for me, restricting the image to 18000px wide, producing a 10MB output file.

montage -background red -tile 10x -geometry +1+1 *png montage.png

I guess there is a bug somewhere with extremely wide files but I don't know exactly. Try small, then go wider until it fails.